# Iptable Rules Https block in Zentyal

Tags: iptables

I am using Zentyal. I want to block https://www.facebook.com with iptables rules. Can you please tell how to block it for my organization's network?

Comment: You would be blocking a large number of IPs... the better way is to use a proxy and then have some blocking object in play there.

Answer (score 1):

To use iptables rule im not sure how to do it but if you wish you can use a proxy in zentyal.

** Look for the tab named Domain Filtering in the HTTP Proxy section

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to block facebook without using IP tables. I used a Zentyal network object to represent all the facebook IP ranges, and then blocked those ranges using the firewall that in the Zentyal web interface.

You can read what others have said about this here:
https://forum.zentyal.org/index.php/topic,16841.msg66809.html#msg66809